# Best example for C# consumimg Java webservice?

Tags: c#, soap

Best example for C# consumimg Java webservice?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you already have your Java WebService running, just follow these steps:

1. Right Click on your project
2. Pick "Add Service Reference" option
3. Put your WSDL's URL
4. Generate client stub (Service Reference)
5. Use the generated classes to access your Java WebService

Hope it helps.

Comment: For the most part C# and java web services are compatible. There are a few cases where they are not. If you run into any strange errors, you can Google the errors and find the workarounds.